# Javascript I'm wondering if I can exchange className with a letter in functions

Tags: javascript

I want to change this:

```
function KeyChange2() { 
    var uI3 = dS229.value; 
    mK1.className = uI3; 
    mK2.className = uI3; 
    mK3.className= uI3; 
}
```

to something like this:

```
function KeyChange2() { 
    var uI3 = dS229.value; 
    var x = className; 
    mK1.x = uI3; 
    mK2.x = uI3; 
    mK3.x = uI3; 
}
```

dS229.value represents an input

Answer (score 6):

You can use bracket notation instead of dot notation to access the properties:

```
function KeyChange2() { 
    var uI3 = dS229.value; 
    var x = 'className'; 
    mK1[x] = uI3; 
    mK2[x] = uI3; 
    mK3[x] = uI3; 
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with bracket notation (when you want to use a variable to access an objects property):

```
function KeyChange2() { 
    var uI3 = dS229.value; 
    var x = className; 
    mK1[x] = uI3; 
    mK2[x] = uI3;
    mK3[x] = uI3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It failed without the quotes when I tried it, but it was really helpful :)